# How do i get embeds to work with discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

So i am making a test command to for my bot and embeds are not work for me here is my code and i have tried looking it up but in my old bot i got it to work but not with cogs

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class TestCog(commands.Cog, name="test command"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    @commands.command(name = "test",
                    usage="",
                    description = "Testtttttt.")
    @commands.cooldown(1, 2, commands.BucketType.member)
    async def test(self, ctx):
      embed=discord.Embed(title="Ping")
      embed.add_field(name="Pong", value="undefined", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed) 

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a `description` in your embed - if you don't want this to hold any value, then you can simply assign it `""`.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class TestCog(commands.Cog, name="test command"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    @commands.command(name = "test",
                    usage="",
                    description = "Testtttttt.")
    @commands.cooldown(1, 2, commands.BucketType.member)
    async def test(self, ctx):
      embed=discord.Embed(title="Ping", description="")
      embed.add_field(name="Pong", value="undefined", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed) 

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
```